# WHERE ISNULL doesn't bring though records where target value IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The title only explains my first attempt, I couldn't think how to word the issue/my need exactly.

I have table job:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[job] 
(
    [jobId]      INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [contractId] INT NOT NULL,
    [districtId] INT NULL,
    [address]    NVARCHAR (255) NULL
);
```

I'm trying to create a function where all of the column values can be optionally passed through to do a filter search.

So far I have:

```
DECLARE
    @jobId          INT,
    @contracId      INT,
    @districtId     INT,
    @addressPart    NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT 
    [jobId],
    [contractId],
    [districtId],
    [address]   
FROM
    [dbo].job
WHERE 
    jobId = ISNULL(@jobId,jobId)
    AND contractId = ISNULL(@contracId, contractId)
    AND [address] LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@addressPart, [address]) + '%'
```

This works, however because the `districtId` can be null in the `Job` table doing the same ISNULL where clause as for `contractId` results in the query to only ever return records where `districtId` is not null, as the '=' condition doesn't work for null values.

I've tried using `COALESCE`

```
AND COALESCE(districtId, 0) = COALESCE(@districtId, 0)
```

But that results in the query only selecting records where `districtId` is null if no `districtId` is specified. It does select the the row with the `districtId` if a 'district' is set. But this is ultimately no good as if any other variable is set which would match a record, if that record has null `districtId` it won't be selected.

I've also tried using OR

```
AND (districtId = ISNULL(@districtId, districtId) OR districtId IS NULL)
```

But this returns everything when the `districtId` is null, but then if a `districtId` is set, it'll get that record, but also still return all records that have `districtId` null.

I can't even think how to do this with a dirty CASE statement, as I'd need to do `districtId =` and as soon as I do that '=' its not going to work as it need to on some level check for null is null which '=' can't do.

Comment: From your question it's not clear to me what you want to get back for the four combinations of `@districtId` is/is not `NULL` and `districtId` is/is not `NULL`. In particular, it's not clear to me if you want to search for rows with `districtId` `NULL` and if so, when. (Meanwhile, I have [this article](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for information on how to do dynamic search conditions "right" in terms of performance -- [`ISNULL` isn't it](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#coalesce).)

Comment: I want the function to be a search, where any combination of the variables can be passed and records which match are returned. So default the 'districtId' is null so the query need to return all records regardless of what the records 'districtId' is. But if a 'districtId' is passed then I need to select the record/s with that id.

Comment: So `districtId = @districtId OR @districtId IS NULL`, then? Note that the optimizer also likes this formulation a lot better than any calculated expressions involving `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` (especially if `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used).

Comment: Catch-all queries have bad performance whether you write them as `(@jobId is null or jobid=@jobid)` or `jobid=(@jobid,jobid)`. Which won't work anyway, because `NULL != NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check separately if `@districtId` is `null` in which case the condition should return `true`:

```
AND (@districtId IS NULL OR districtId = @districtId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to include the column in the COALESCE to handle the param = column value

```
 AND COALESCE(districtId ,0) = COALESCE(@districtId, districtId,0)
```

Comment: oh snap! Well that was a quick fix, thank you!

Comment: @Vereonix that's not a fix. The query won't use any indexes now and scan the entire table